# How is it OR What is it like

Tags: grammar

In the region I live, I've heard some people saying, "How is it to play golf wearing sneakers?" Although I believe that it should be 'What is it like to play golf wearing sneakers?' Am I right in this?

Answer (score 1):

"What is it like" is usually followed by an infinitive (*to play*) or a present participle (*playing*). Grammatically and idiomatically, it almost always works.

"How is it" is usually followed by a present participle. Grammatically, it doesn't work as often as "what is it like", but people still use it even if it isn't grammatically correct.

In casual conversation, it's not a problem to break grammar rules. In more formal contexts, where you have to speak English perfectly, you would probably use "what is it like".

Comment: How about a bunch of examples?

Comment: Eating ice cream with international friends: "How is it living in Turkey?" "What was it like to move here?"

At a White House dinner: "What is it like to spend millions of dollars on cruise missiles while Flint's water is still poisoned?"